# how to check all my followers and followings on Tweetdeck website

Tags: tweetdeck

I can't find the whole list of my followings and followers on Tweetdeck website. 
Is it possible to find them?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Friend or Follow](http://friendorfollow.com/) to check. Tweetdeck doesn't have this feature & opens twitter page.